# Where do you report typos at developer.android.com?

Tags: android

I found a typo on the guide section at developer.android.com, but I can't find a link/email to report the typo to.

I don't want to report it on the Android Developers Google group, as its a typo and not a technical question.

Anyone have an email address or link I can use to report typos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this with a grain of salt, but I *think* you can report typos on the [Google Code page](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list). If you search the issue tracker for "typo" you get a bunch of [other hits](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=typo&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles), some of which were fixed or followed-up on, and they all seem to at least be marked 'Medium' severity.

I also saw [this archived android-developers post](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg72043.html), where someone suggested to open a ticket on the tracker, but I don't think the poster is a Google employee or anything.

Comment: I ended up taking your advice and posted the typo bug there (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11905).

Comment: Filing bug reports at b.android.come is a great thing to do. But you can do something even better and contribute a patch at source.android.com :)